Images are broken in Nextjs app hosted in s3 as static app
I have deployed an simple next js app over s3 as a static website, the website runs though but all the images seems broken 404 not found error I upload the build app of nextjs using command - next build.
Before build the images are in - project/src/assests
After build when I checked images that are 404 showing image location - http://buckets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Flogo.a7ef02f9.png&w=128&q=75
How can I fix this issue.
I tried several methods like - module.exports = { images: { loader: 'akamai', path: '', }, }; but nothing working

You should locate your image files in /public folder under your project's root folder. Instead of /project/src/assets, move your image files to /project/public.

So Now I need to move  image files to /project/public and then change into every file then create build again and upload over s3?

yes, exactly. Let me know if it doesn't work either. If so, there might be some other factors that you need to consider.
